# How to set Id Attribute for html elements in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I use Ajax with php

```
$("#test1").click(
     ....
    function(data){
      document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML=data;
    }
)
```

php return data

```
echo "<input type='text' id='test'>";
```

How to get the Id attribute from innerHTML? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: You're using jQuery to bind to the click event... so just use $('#test2').attr('id')

Comment: @AdamJeffers but I can only see the content <input type='text' id='test'> inside innerHTML, I cant see the <input type='text' id='test'> from page source

Comment: Once the inner html is set. A subsequent instruction of $("#test").id would get the id field. Or you can use document.getElementById("test").id without any jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get it from innerHTML to get the id is simply:

```
document.getElementById("test2").id;//Gets the id for element test2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the inner HTML value by using javascript. 

By using  : **var a = document.getElementById('test').value**

a will have the required response.

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you use attr method it should works like this

```
var a = $('#test').attr('id');
```